# How do I get maxima to simplify logs usefully

Tags: maxima

I have a maxima script that generates terms where after logcontract is run I get an expression with many terms of the type

```
log((A^n)/(B^n))
```

where both A and B are non trivial expressions

how can I get maxima to rearrange this into `n*log(A/B)` so that I can then perform a variable substitution and factor in terms of `log(A/B)` ?

I explicitly need it in the form `log(A/B)` and not `log(A)-log(B)`

A and B may be assumed positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, take two. Here's another approach via pattern matching.

```
(%i1) matchdeclare ([aa, bb, nn], all);
(%o1)                         done
(%i2) defrule (mylogrule, log((bb^nn)/(aa^nn)), nn*log(bb/aa));
                                 nn
                               bb           bb
(%o2)          mylogrule : log(----) -> log(--) nn
                                 nn         aa
                               aa
(%i3) log(A^4/B^4);
                                  4
                                 A
(%o3)                        log(--)
                                  4
                                 B
(%i4) apply1 (%o3, mylogrule);
                                  A
(%o4)                       4 log(-)
                                  B
(%i5) log(A^k/B^k);
                                  k
                                 A
(%o5)                        log(--)
                                  k
                                 B
(%i6) apply1 (%o5, mylogrule);
                                A
(%o6)                       log(-) k
                                B
```

Note that `apply1` finds `log(...)` expressions and applies the rule even in complex expressions (not just expressions where the top-level operator is `log`).

I wrote the rule as `log(bb^nn/aa^nn)` because `log(aa^nn/bb^nn)` comes out as `-nn*log(bb/aa)` ... which isn't wrong but it's inconvenient. Probably has to do with the order in which arguments are matched; I didn't investigate.

Comment: That works. the log(aa^nn/bb^nn) vs log(bb^nn/aa^nn) is seemingly a function of the expressions A and B, this can be dealt with with another substitution afterwards though.

Answer (score 1):

I find the following combination of `logexpand` (with the `super` option) and `logcontract` seems to do the job.

```
(%i1) log((A^n)/(B^n)), logexpand=super;
(%o1)                  log(A) n - log(B) n
(%i2) %, logcontract;
                                A
(%o2)                       log(-) n
                                B
```

Comment: Hmm, just tried , it works for the general case n, however if n is an integer number, it reverts to the undesired behaviour

Comment: Huh, yeah, you're right. According to the documentation for `logcontract` that's exactly what it's supposed to do; that it worked for `n` was just a happy accident. I tried the `logconcoeffp` option but couldn't get anything to work. At this point I think a pattern matching solution (via `tellsimp`, `tellsimpafter`, `defrule` or `defmatch`) is possible. Let me think about it.